# Compare values and return the name of the highest value

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

```
+-------+--------+
| Names | Values |
+-------+--------+
| A     | 25     |
+-------+--------+
| B     | 12.5   |
+-------+--------+
| C     | 37.5   |
+-------+--------+
```

How can I compare values and return the name of the highest value?

I am using LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 0):

The normal `VLOOKUP` function assumes the values are in the leftmost column, so we can use `LOOKUP` instead to search in the correct column.

```
=LOOKUP(MAX(B1:B3);B1:B3;A1:A3)
```

Documentation: [LOOKUP](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LOOKUP_function), [MAX](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MAX_function)